# "Hash sum mismatch" on trying to install Kile

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, kile

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 I was trying to install Kile in order to edit `.tex` files. But this message showed up on attempting to install Kile and Updates:

```
W:Failed to fetch
gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
Hash Sum mismatch , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Now I can't install any software at all. What can I do?

EDITING :
[image]

I have done which you said . But now I'm trying to install Okular but this is showing :-(

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11593258&postcount=2.

From the post above:

> Remove the files with

```
sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

> then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo rm -rf `find /var/lib/apt/lists/ | grep -v gpg`
```

EDIT: Okay, try this:

```
sudo fuser -vvv /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
LANG=C;sudo apt-get clean
LANG=C;sudo apt-get autoclean
LANG=C;sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo dpkg --configure -a
LANG=C;sudo apt-get -f install
LANG=C;sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824 && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(from https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/194077)

Comment: Please check my editing on the post .

Comment: Okay, see my editing on my answer :)